# Driver for TP-Link tl-wn722n stops working

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, usb, kernel

I am using Ubuntu 16.04(.5), with this kernel model: 4.10.0-42-generic, on a HP laptop with a WiFi card model that does not have a linux driver (yet...hopefully).

In the meantime I decided to use a wireless USB adapter, specifically a TP-LINK tl-wn722n.
Honestly I am not sure what chipset the adapter uses (I know there is a Atheros and a Realtek one out there), but `lspci` gives the following output

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 35)
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 35)
    00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 35)
    00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SATA Controller (rev 35)
    00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 35)
    00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 35)
    00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 35)
    00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 35)
    00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #4 (rev 35)
    00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 35)
    00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller (rev 35)
    01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

while `lsusb` just shows an empty field

```
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1bcf:2c9b Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.  
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
    Bus 001 Device 009: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9500 [Galaxy S4] / GT-I9250 [Galaxy Nexus] (network tethering)
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:010c  
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I know the USB module is the WiFi one because it disappears as soon as I unplug it.
In order to get it to work, I followed line by line the script shown in the following page:

https://gist.github.com/h4cc/51750fa6843bf2c7e1ee21a003b923cf

for those that do not wanna follow the link this is the script:

```
    sudo apt-get install git dkms git make build-essential
    cd /usr/src
    sudo git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
    sudo dkms add ./rtl8188eu
    sudo dkms build 8188eu/1.0
    sudo dkms install 8188eu/1.0
    sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

and the USB adapter works just fine...until it doesn't anymore.
The first time I installed it it worked for about a week, then all of a sudden the the adapter wasn't recognized anymore. Since I could really not find a solution I re-installed Ubuntu (and the driver of course), just to have it stop working the very next day.
I cannot really think of a reason why it could happen.
The first time I thought it could be because I ran a `apt-get upgrade` , and that could have messed with the kernel, that's why I did not upgrade the new installation (I did upgrade only firefox, to be fair).

What I tried to do, was reinstalling the dkms module. At first `dkms status` showed that there were two builds for the same driver installed: the one matching my kernel version (4.10.0-42-generic), and another one (4.8.0-36-generic).
I first used `dkms uninstall -m 8188eu -v 1.0`, which only uninstalled the build that matched my kernel, afterward I also uninstall the other one using the `-k` dkms option. Then I went through the installation process again (from `dkms build`), just to find myself stuck at `modprobe 8188eu`, where I get a

```
    modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8188eu': Exec format error
```

`dkms status`, at this point, gives the following output:

```
   8188eu, 1.0, 4.10.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
   8188eu, 1.0, 4.8.0-36-generic, x86_64: built
   virtualbox, 5.0.40, 4.10.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
   virtualbox, 5.0.40, 4.8.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
```

and the USB does not work

I should probably post more descriptive output, but I'm not that familiar with linux so I don't really know what could be useful. I prefer editing later with more info, if needed.

As a side note, the `lspci` output:

```
   Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

refers to the WiFi card my laptop is equipped with(I think at least). If anyone also knows about a way to get THAT to work instead it'd also be amazing (even thought I'm kind of curious why the adapter doesn't work).

Thank you in advance